# Why can I run a python script even with no execute/'x' permission?

Tags: python, linux, permissions

I have a simple python script called helloWorld.py created by a user called Bob with permissions set for just read for groups and others. How is it possible for the another other user Mary to be able to run the script without it being executable?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bob bob   21 Sep 29 20:56 helloWorld.py

mary@kali:/home/bob/Scripts$ python helloWorld.py
Hello World
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the execute bit to run a program directly, such as by typing `./helloWorld.py`. If you run a script via an interpreter (`python` in `python helloWorld.py`), the only the interpreter needs the execute bit, and the file only needs the read bit.